# Custom CentOS 7 and Veracrypt Parition

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, veracrypt

### Problem

I am trying to generate a Live USB stick with a custom CentOS 7.6 ISO which would include a separate Veracrypt partition. At this point, I can successfully customize the ISO and write it on a USB drive, but I have not figure out a way to have a separate Veracrypt partition on the same drive.

Ideally, I would like to have 2 partitions: 
First partition, read-only hosting the custom CentOS 7.6 ISO.
Second partition, writeable Veracrypt non-system partition

### Current State

At this point, I can successfully generate a bootable ISO file and write on a USB drive using `dd`. The USB drive successfully boot into CentOS. However it currently uses a single partition, which I suppose is defined within the ISO when generated by xorriso/mkisofs/isohybrid.

I previously attempted to generate a 2 partition USB drive using `sgdisk` (I'm trying to have everything automated via a Bash script). Since `sgdisk` or any other tool like `fdisk` or `parted` does not let me write directly from sector 0, the boot sector of the ISO is never loaded and I fail to boot the OS from the USB drive, even after making the partition with the "legacy_boot" flag.

I am guessing that one potential solution would be to write somesort of bootloader via `dd` that would then jump to the first partition containing the CentOS bootloader. However I'm not sure if this would be the best solution and if it is, I wouldn't know how to implement it properly.

Another alternative would be to have a Veracrypt container included within the ISO and mapped out when the USB drive loads (via keyfiles, which is fine), but then I would not be able to make the OS partition read-only.

This is what I use to generate the ISO, in case this is relevant:

```
        xorriso -as mkisofs \
                -U -r -v -T -J \
                -joliet-long \
                -V "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810" \
                -volset "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810" \
                -A "CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810" \
                -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
                -c isolinux/boot.cat \
                -no-emul-boot \
                -boot-load-size 4 \
                -boot-info-table \
                -eltorito-alt-boot \
                -e isolinux/efiboot.img \
                -no-emul-boot -graft-points \
                -isohybrid-mbr /usr/share/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin \
                -o /tmp/stage/centos7-custom-boot.iso .
```

### Question(s)

1) Can I actually have a USB drive with 2 partitions: 1 that would be read-only and boot the OS, while the second one would writeable and encrypted using Veracrypt

2) How?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the ISO onto a USB stick and use a partition editor like fdisk
to create a new partition. The xorriso run with -isohybrid-mbr produced 
already an MBR partition 1 which covers the ISO. /sbin/fdisk will recognize 
it and offer to add more partitions in the remaining free space on the stick.
Then you would apply encryption setup and filesystem formatting as
with a fresh partition on hard disk.

(Your ISO does not expose the EFI image as partition. I.e. it will boot
from USB stick only via legacy CSM (BIOS).
Usual EFI bootable ISOs have the EFI image as partition of valid GPT or of MBR with
invalid GPT, which complicates the issue for the partition editor. If you 
get offered to convert MBR table to GPT, then don't do. Rather discard GPT
in this case. If valid GPT is present, then you need to let the partition
editor move the backup table to the end of the USB stick.)

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: Perfect, used `fdisk` with the `n` option and accepted the defaults. Then used Veracrypt to create a container on the resulting partition. Everything booted without any issue, and was able to mount the encrypted partition within CentOS live. Thanks!